# How to enable Only one button and making User Interaction No

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, user-interaction

In my project in one view i want to make all the view **disable** except **one button**, So i am using

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

As i have many components it is difficult to enable and disable every component so i am using it.

But I want to enable one button there are many buttons.

Comment: just loop every subview and disable them and enable that button

Answer (score 3):

As per XLC You can do like

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
    {
        if (view.tag==101)// set your button tag that you don't wont disable
            [ view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        else
            [ view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (UIView *viewButton in [self.view subviews]) 
{
 if ([viewButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) //In case you want check only for the buttons.
   {
    if (viewButton.tag==1)//Make sure that you have already set the tag=1 for the button,which you don't want to disable
    {
    [viewButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    else
    {
    [viewButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one hope this helps you

```
for (id subview in [self.view subviews]) 
{
   if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]&&[subview tag]==1)
   {
         [subview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   }
   else
   {
         [subview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`
Then your entire view getting disable including subviews.
So better to loop all subviews and disable and enable according to requirement.